# Conditionally load a VS Package

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsx

I am building a VSPackage, and I use the `ProvideAutoLoad` attribute to load the package.

Now, I want to control when the package kicks in. This package has an Editor Classifier and a few IOleCommandTargets implemented. I would like to disable the package unless there are certain conditions that are met.

What would be the best way to do this? I have looked at `ProvideAutoLoad`'s parameters, none seem to help me here.

Comment: What condition do you want the package to load in? There either might be a better AutoLoad parameter, or (even better) avoid use of AutoLoad and do something more targeted.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski - In this case I want to check if the project is intended for use with this package. The way I check this is to check existence of certain meta files and project reference. Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you will have to load your package when a solution is loaded, and check those conditions. Try to make your package as small as possible (for faster loading) and the condition checks as fast as possible.